# Regex - how to extract number which falls on specified ID?

Tags: regex, jmeter

I'm trying to extract the number '1' that appears on the line with the ID I'm feeding (i.e. 12072).

I've been trying for the past 2 hours to get this regex to work but I'm at a loss. So far I've got

```
12072.*?(\d+)(?!.*\d)
```

but this extracts me everything from 12072 to the 1. Here's the text:

```
<td id="12072" scope="#999999" bgcolor="#999999" style="width: 65; color:#999999" align="center"  onclick="DaySelect(this)" title="">1</td>
<td id="12073" scope="#999999" bgcolor="#999999" style="width: 65; color:#999999" align="center"  onclick="DaySelect(this)" title="">1</td>
```

How can I match **just** the number 1 from the end of the line of the specified ID, surely there's a way to do this?

Help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your match will be in group 1

```
"12072"[^>]*>(\d+)
```

And here is an explanation

```
Match the characters “12073” literally «12073»
Match any character that is NOT a “>” «[^>]*»
   Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «*»
Match the character “>” literally «>»
Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(\d+)»
   Match a single digit 0..9 «\d+»
      Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
```

Comment: What language are you using or is jmeter a language?

Comment: Going to test it now. JMeter is actually a load testing tool. I'm using JMeters inbuilt regex library: http://jakarta.apache.org/oro/ "The Jakarta-ORO Java classes are a set of text-processing Java classes that provide Perl5 compatible regular expressions, AWK-like regular expressions, glob expressions, and utility classes for performing substitutions, splits, filtering filenames, etc. "

Answer (score 1):

```
"12072"[^>]+\>([^\<])
```

Included quotes in case you were searching for, say, 120. Without quotes it would match both lines.

Also takes all text content of the tag, nut just digits.

< and > might not need to be escaped in jmeter. If not, remove the leading slashes.

Answer (score 1):

You can try better [XPath Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor) with xpath query like

```
//td[@id='${id}']/text()
```

where `${id}` is jmeter variable set to value you need (12072 e.g.), or simply

```
//td[@id='12072']/text()
```

if you don't need parametrization.

NOTE: ensure that [Use Tidy (tolerant parser)](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor) option is CHECKED on XPath Extractor's control panel - required for processing html response using xpath.